# Parallel execution in $2 \times 4$ kernels

Tags: parallelization, scripting

Let's say I have 8 CPUs available on a single node.
I want to run two instances of the same script (from command line with wolframscript in args > out &) on that node in parallel.
Is there a way to ensure that both script will each use 4 different kernels during the execution? I.e. to dedicate 4 kernels out of 8 to each script?

Comment: AFAIK that should be possible. Using `StartKernels[4]` in each of them should do that. What did you try so far, are there any problems which make you ask that question?

Comment: I tried that already but it looks like each instance sees 8 kernels, not only 4.

Comment: Mathematica processorCount         = 4

Launching kernels...
{r08-node14, r08-node14, r08-node14, r08-node14}

Mathematica MaxLicenceSubprocesses = Infinity

Mathematica configuredKernels      = 
{SubKernels`LocalKernels`LocalMachine[4, 
SubKernels`LocalKernels`LowerPriority -> True]}

Mathematica kernels closing at: 2018-03-15T12:16:58

Mathematica kernelCount            = 8

Comment: sorry, that should have been `LaunchKernels` of course. I am not sure how to interpred your last comment. Is that the output of your script? I can guess what you have used in the script, but it would be helpful if you would show that code in your question. I am also not sure how I should understand "each instance sees 8 kernels", does that mean `$KernelCount` equals 8? Have you tried an explicit `LaunchKernels[4]` before calling any of the parallel functionality?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Both scripts do a LaunchKernels[4]. After what, when I issue a $KernelCount it returns 8.

Comment: if that is the case, it looks like a potential bug, from a notebook the same code behaves as documented. But without an explicit example and some details about your version and OS we can not confirm or suggest workarounds. Please edit your question and provide a stripped down version of the failing script, that might also trigger more people to answer/comment...